# Android M getSharedPreferences is crashing in release build

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a problem with the use of the function **getPreferences/getSharedPreferences** under Android M (Nexus 5/Clean install)

When debugging is turned on (debug&release build), there is no problem, but when i make a **release build with debugging off**, then the app is loading and will only display a white screen and the Logcat is displaying:

> W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.*.*.*-1/lib/arm

The following line of code gives the problem:

```
 SharedPreferences login = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("AUTOLOGIN", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

And I have tried this line also (same problem):

```
 SharedPreferences login2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

In my Manifest file I tried to turn off Autobackup, but the result is the same.
On other devices running lower Android versions there is no problem

Is there anyway to get my app working under Android M, or do I have to skip the shared preferences?

Comment: Is there anyone who recognizes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was a timing problem, the debug slowed everything down

Comment: Can you share your solution? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem initialising SharedPreferences in release build (proguard activated, debugable false). My error log was (saw in Crashlytics, not in the logcat):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
...
```

I fixed it adding this code in the proguard-rules.pro file:

```
-keepattributes Signature #
```

Maybe it is the same error.